# CSS content tag in style disallows to drag element

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop, draggable

I need to make draggable elements in html with image changeable through replacing style of the element. The picture I insert with content style tag. But when I use content, the element looses ability to be draggable. Is it possible to make element with content to be draggable?

The simpliest example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   .no-picture {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 10px black;
   }
   .with-picture {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 10px black;
    content: url(myimage.png);
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="no-picture" draggable=true></div>
  <div class="with-picture" draggable=true></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The div element with "no-picture" style can be dragged, but those with "with-picture" does not react on dragging attempts (tested in Chrome). The only difference in content style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, use the `background` property instead:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .no-picture {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border: solid 10px black;
    }
    
    .with-picture {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border: solid 10px black;
      background: url("https://picsum.photos/200");
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="no-picture" draggable=true></div>
  <div class="with-picture" draggable=true></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is a workable option. But background is not so convenient as content because the size of div must be the same as picture size. With content this takes place automatically, but with background I have to set correct width and height manually.

But if there is no way to make content be compatible with dragging, I would use your variant.

Comment: There are a huge number of ways to customise the `background` property from the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background), Including ways to adjust the image inside the element. Some of them can be a bit fiddley but they have some good examples